# Cassandra Python Driver Error callback shows No error

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I'm right now performing load tests on an API endpoint that saves data into cassandra. In general it works well, but when I perform async insert operations I get the following messages on the error callback:

```
ERROR:root:Query '<BatchStatement type=UNLOGGED, statements=382, consistency=ONE>' failed: errors={}, last_host=XXXXX
```

I perform batch insert the following way:

```
query_template = self.query_template(table, columns, values, ttl, insertion_timestamp)

statement = self.session.prepare(query_template)
statement.consistency_level = self.write_consistency_level
batch = BatchStatement(batch_type=BatchType.UNLOGGED, retry_policy=RetryPolicy.RETRY,
                           consistency_level=self.write_consistency_level)
for elem in list_of_dictionary:
    values = [elem[key] for key in field_list]
    batch.add(statement, values)

if async:
    future = self.session.execute_async(batch, values)
    future.add_errback(error_handler, batch)
else:
    self.session.execute(batch, values)
```

With the error callback handler:

```
def default_error_handler(exc, batch):
   """
   Default callback function that is triggered when the cassandra async   operation failed
   :param exception:
   """

   logging.error("Query '%s' failed: %s", batch, exc)
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue.

It is a client side error of the type `OperationTimedOut`. You can find it in here:

[https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/1fd961a55a06a3ab739a3995d09c53a1b0e35fb5/cassandra/**init**.py](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/1fd961a55a06a3ab739a3995d09c53a1b0e35fb5/cassandra/__init__.py)

I suggest to log in addition the type of the exception in your callback handler like this

```
def default_error_handler(exc, batch):
    """
    Default callback function that is triggered when the cassandra  async operation failed
    :param exception:
    """


    logging.error("Batch '%s' failed with exception '%s' of type '%s' ", batch, exc, type(exc))
```

I will now try to solve our issues!